# How to loop through tags using get query builder in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How do I loop through tags of a belongtoMany relationship without using all() query but by using the get() query builder. When I use all() the tags are on the right post but when I use get() the tags are not appearing on the right post.

How do I get the tags to appear on the correct post?

So here is what my current models look like for the Ad and Tag model.

---

```
table 1: ad   | table 2: tag  | table 3: ad_tag
        name  |       tagname |          tag_id
              |               |          ad_id
```

---

```
public function render()
    {


        $ads = Ad::join('adtypes', 'ads.adtype_id', 'adtypes.id')
        ->join('industries', 'ads.industry_id', 'industries.id')
        ->simplePaginate($this->perpage);

        // $ads = Ad::all();
        // dd($ads);

        return view('livewire.ad-table', compact('ads'));
    }
```

---

```
       @foreach($ads as $ad)
                <tr>

                 <td scope=row> <img src="/images/{{$ad->image}}" height="100px" width="100px" alt=""> </td>
                <td scope="row">{{$ad->name}}</td>

                <td scope="row"> 
                    @foreach($ad->tags as $tag)
                    <span class="badge badge-dark">{{$tag->tagname}}</span>
                      @endforeach

                </td>


                </tr>
                @endforeach
```

---

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Models;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    
    class Ad extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;
        public function tags()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Tag');
    
        }
    
        public function industry()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Industry');
        }
    
    
        public function adtype()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Adtype');
        }
    
        public static function search($search)
        {
            return  empty($search) ? static::query()
                    : static::query()->where('company', 'like','%'.$search. '%' );
                   
        }

  public function adTag()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Adtag');
    }
    }
```

---

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function ads()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Ad');
    }
}


public function adtag()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Tag');
}
```

---

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Adtag extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;


    public function ads()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Ad');
    }
   

    public function tag()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Tag');
    }
}
```

Comment: Its easy and simple ,just use elequent relationship, laravel documentaion for this part is great and helpsfull

Answer (score 0):

Make atleast 3 model
Ad => table ad

add relationship to ad_tag

```
public function addTag()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\AddTag');
}
```

Tag => table tag
AdTag => table ad_tag

```
public function tag()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Tag');
}
```

and then in controller

```
$ads = Ad::get();
```

in views

```
@foreach($ads as $ad)
            <tr>

             <td scope=row> <img src="/images/{{$ad->image}}" height="100px" width="100px" alt=""> </td>
            <td scope="row">{{$ad->name}}</td>

            <td scope="row"> 
                @foreach($ad->addTag as $addTag)
                <span class="badge badge-dark">{{$addTag->tag->tagname}}</span>
                  @endforeach

            </td>


            </tr>
            @endforeach
```

Comment: Hey could you take a look at my updated code would it be like that? @UmarHasan